# Stopping a popover window becoming the key window

Tags: cocoa, macos, popover

I am trying to write a Mac application which runs in the menubar, which when clicked, displays an iOS-like popover. Similar to Flexibit's Fantastical, or The Iconfactory's Take Five.

I am using [INPopoverController](http://forrst.com/posts/INPopoverController_Customizable_Cocoa_popover-gQZ) which seems to work great.
My problem is that when the user clicks on anything in the popover view, the popover becomes the key window. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`INPopoverWindow`](https://github.com/indragiek/INPopoverController/blob/master/INPopoverWindow.m):

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

means that the popover can become a key window. You can either change it to return `NO`, or subclass `INPopoverWindow` and override that method to return `NO`.